# posts_per_page is set to 1, returns 50 posts

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, limit, custom-post-type

I'm trying to get the latest post in a custom post type:

```php
$query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'         => 'some_custom_post_type',
    'posts_per_page'    => 1,
    'orderby'           => 'date',
    'order'             => 'DESC'
));
```

For some weird reason, this returns 50 posts. I `echo`ed the SQL from `$query->request`, and I can see that the `LIMIT` is set to 50:

```sql
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts
WHERE 1=1
    AND wp_posts.post_type = 'some_custom_post_type'
    AND (
        wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
        OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private'
    )
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
LIMIT 0, 50
```

Switching `post_limits` instead of `posts_per_page` yields the same weird result.

---

**Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?**

Comment: use `posts_per_page` with `paged` parameter to show result with pagination

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'         => 'some_custom_post_type',
    'posts_per_page'    => 1,
    'showposts'         => 1,
    'orderby'           => 'date',
    'order'             => 'DESC'
));
```

Comment: That doesn't change anything.

Comment: add `wp_reset_query()` above query ie

`wp_reset_query();
$query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'         => 'some_custom_post_type',
    'posts_per_page'    => 1,
    'showposts'         => 1,
    'orderby'           => 'date',
    'order'             => 'DESC'
));`